# Quick reply on Facebook messenger problem

Tags: javascript, chatbot, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-chatbot

i'm having problems with the quick_reply in the facebook messenger chat bot;

the problem is: i created a 2 option quick reply button but i don't know how continue the flow after the click of one of the 2 button.

here the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/daffodil-authorization?path=app.js:267:3

how it works?: if u tap "what is the meaning of life", 2 quick reply button will appear "42" and "chocolate", but at the click, the bot will answer you as usual (repeating what you write); how can i allow the bot to listen "42" or "chocolate" and go on with something else?

Comment: Can you please post your code directly into the question and not through a link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/htkpfqL3/    it's too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Quick Replies**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies) are different from **[Buttons](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/buttons)** in that their payload do not return as **[Postback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/postback)** messages, but instead are delivered as normal messages as if the user typed and sent the message themselves.

It is literally just a way for the user to return a *reply, quicker* than typing. So your bot is treating it like a normal message, because it is sent as a normal message.

So either your code needs to parse and catch normal incoming messages, looking for "42" or "chocolate". Or change from using a Quick Reply to an actual Postback Button, so that you can catch them returned through Postback messages instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use [Quick Replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies) and then catch the user's response on them!

My bot is not looking for buttons titles (your "42" and "chocolate", I excluded them from my echo function) and depends on the "Payload" runs with the next action.

"When a quick reply is tapped, the buttons are dismissed, and the title of the tapped button is posted to the conversation as a message. A messages event will be sent to your webhook that contains the button title **and an optional payload**."

Added payload(used 2 k-v pairs) to quick reply buttons:

```
response_sent_text = "My text"
buttons = (
            {
                "content_type": "text",
                "title": "Python_title",
                "payload": json.dumps(
                    {"id": i_id, "language": "python"}
                ),
            },
        )
        bot.send_message(
            recipient_id,
            message={"text": response_sent_text, "quick_replies": buttons},
        )
```

And used this to catch:

```
for message in messaging:
    payload = (message.get("message", {}).get("quick_reply", {}).get("payload"))
        if payload:
            returned_payload = json.loads(payload)
            if returned_payload["language"] == "python":
                pass
```